# How can I declare external js in defer location using taglib?

Tags: grails, resources

I need to declare external js in `defer` "location". I thought that
`<r:external uri="http://cdn.connect.mail.ru/js/loader.js" disposition="defer"/>` will work but it's just place `<script...` code where it's called.

How can I declare external js in defer location using taglib?

Grails 2.0+, resources plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you described, the r:external tag unfortunately seems to not respect the default disposition for JavaScript, which is "defer". Also, according to the documentation, the [r:external](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-resources/ref/Tags/external.html) tag does not provide a "disposition" attribute to explicitly declare this.
The [r:script](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-resources/ref/Tags/script.html) tag correctly places scripts at the bottom of the body, but it does not provide a "src" attribute because its use is only intended for "inline" JavaScript.

I think the nicest way to work around this missing feature is to define a resource module in your ApplicationResources.groovy file

```
modules = {
    ...
    mail_loader {
        resource url: "http://cdn.connect.mail.ru/js/loader.js"
    }
    ...
```

and then require it using your TagLib.

```
out << r.require(module: "mail_loader")
```

As already mentioned, the default disposition of JavaScript resources is "defer", so you don't need to explicitly define the disposition in your case.